# Is there a way to format as code with Highlight.js and disable all syntax changes (color, italics, etc.)?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to format as code without [Highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter), applying further syntax formatting?

I ask because I just answered a question related to `sed` *[How to fetch a particular string using a sed command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65247313/how-to-fetch-a-particular-string-using-a-sed-command/65247848#65247848)* and the syntax highlighting made both the `sed` expression itself, and then the example using it hard to read due to application of partial coloring and partial italics, e.g.

[image]

and then at the end of the question showing the example of use:

[image]

My thought was it would be more readable if I could just leave it as plain-text without syntax highlight. Is that possible?

Comment: `none` directly after the code-fence should work

Comment: `\`\`\`lang-none` will disable highlighting.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. I usually do 4-spaces, but I'll try code fences.

Comment: Yep, close as dupe. (or do you want me to delete?) The `<!-- language: none -->` worked well on the question.